# External IP + SSL

Tags: https, ip, port

how can i use the external ip of my centos7 instance with **https**, like for example **https**://external_ip to open an application like **https://external_ip:Port/my_application**

Answer (score 0):

Generate a self-sign certificate using openssl.

Check this out here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/9662626

Open a https port on your webserver. Set the certificate in the config (I can't be specific here because I don't know about your operating system and your choice of web server). Finally setup a reverse proxy to proxy the web server port to your app port.

Comment: thanks for your reaction, SE = Centos7, web = apache
but can i use the automatic certificates with which i connected on the instance via ssh on the browser

Comment: What do you mean by the automatic certificate? And I'm just a bit confused with this ssh and browser thing. Are you using aws ec2 or gcp or something similar?

Comment: The key that you got is for ssh not https. The two protocols are different.

Comment: ok I understand, I thought the same key could still be used
thank you

Comment: not totally, but thanks anyway.
I will approach the assistance of gcp for the rest

Comment: Alright. But I don't think gcp will be UN charge getting this whole https thing to work. Unless they are also a certificate authority.